# What could be a more efficient replacement of this data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, performance

I have a class named Pair which is constructed to hold pairs of integer values.

```
public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> 
{

    public int word1;//1st integer of the pair
    public int word2;//2nd integer of the pair

    public Pair(int w1, int w2) 
    {
        word1 = w1;
        word2 = w2;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair input) 
    {
        if (input.word1 == word1) 
        {
            if (input.word2 == word2) 
                return 0;
            else if (input.word2 < word2)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;

        } 
        else if (input.word1 == word2) 
        {
            if (input.word2 == word1)
                return 0;
            else if (input.word2 < word1)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;

        } 
        else if (input.word1 > word1)
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }

}
```

What can I use as a better and efficient way of storing my integer pairs instead of this class? Can I use an array list or something? would that be more efficient or not?

Comment: One immediate improvement would be to name your members min and max. Then, in your constructor, always store the smaller value in min and the larger value in max. Your compareTo will become much smaller.

Comment: After that point, the question of efficiency can't be answered without knowing the purpose of your class.

Comment: @Chandranshu - not only that, he's currently breaking `Comparable` because it's not reflexive - sorts are no longer guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - +1 for noting that. I didn't even read the whole compareTo method!

Comment: I think you should take this code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for more review comments.

Comment: [Do I look like a Guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: Dilini - what information do we have about `word1` and `word2`?  Like, are they both guaranteed to be positive?  (If so, you can vastly simplify some comparisons with things like `word2 - word1`, which returns > 0 if `word2` is greater).  Yeah, we need more information in general here.

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to achieve is some other data structure which would be much efficient instead of the pair class, because it takes a lot of time when I use this structure to store the pairs. The compareTo method is not that important. If you could tell me which would be a better structure even without the function in compareTo method that would be helpful :)

Comment: You are already using the most efficient structure. Don't even start considering an array or ArrayList.

Comment: @Dilini Could you tell us when does it takes a lot of time? When you are allocating memory or when your i.e. sorting a list?

Comment: yeah when allocating memory

Comment: I bet you have no proof of your actual bottleneck, you are just guessing. Construction of such trivial objects as yours is amng the most heavily optimized operations on the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

A typical pattern to implement lexicographical comparison, this is what you seem trying to achieve, is:

```
int r; 

r = Integer.compare(word1, input.word1);

if(r==0) return r;

return Integer.compare(word2, input.word2);
```